# WPF PRISM 5.0 & Unity IoC: Trying to implement re-usable view w/ PopUpWindow supporting dependency injection

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism, prism-5

This is my first post on StackOverflow so forgive me if I am not completely clear.

My WPF project uses PRISM 5.0 and Unity as the container. This is my first project using PRISM and Unity.

In my application, I am loading a View into my MainWindow correctly. This view displays a friendly version of information about an item. I have an edit button on this screen and I would like it to call up a modal window with the appropriate controls for editing this item. So far, I have chosen the InteractionRequestTrigger -> PopUpWindowAction approach as it was the most straight-forward seeming approach to achieve the result. I am not married to this approach.

However, I noticed I am not able to get dependency injection to work for the ViewModel constructor for the View I am trying to use in the modal. This is probably because I have not registered the View with a Region or done any of the associated leg work and the PopUpWindowAction is just plopping my user control onto a plain form if I had to guess.

My question is, can I achieve a modal dialog passing a custom View and ViewModel and have it behave as the parent View and ViewModel calling it? That is, supporting Dependency Injection and the like. After doing the edit logic, I'd like to ideally re-use the View and ViewModel for my add item functionality, but I am thinking I will be registering that View with the "Main Region" of my Shell and as such, would like to use dependency injection there as well.

Hopefully this is clear. I didn't think a code example would really help much here, but if so, let me know and I can put together a simple example illustrating the above.

Answer (score 0):

I would not provide tight-coupling between my main view-model and the view-model for my modal dialog.

Instead, I would consider using the EventAggregator that Prism provides to publish notifications that my main view-model can subscribe to and react accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Scott. To make sure I follow, are you suggesting I implement my modal View and ViewModel in the same manner that I have implement my parent View and ViewModel and register the view with a region on a separate window (abandoning the PopUpWindowAction presumably), using the EventAggregator to communicate between the ViewModels? Or, are you recommending to keep utilizing the PopUpWindowAction, but pass it a View comprised of a ContentControl Region and register my Modal View with that region?

Comment: Yes. However, I would not worry about RegionManager in regards to any dialogs.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my comment to be a little more detailed. I'm not sure if you are notified of edits or not.

Comment: The only reason I mention registering the Modal View with the RegionManager is because I have some singleton services I would like to dependency inject (constructor) into the Modal ViewModel and I may want to re-use this view altogether in a Region elsewhere in my application.

Comment: Okay, well, Prism provides a way to do this. However, I do not have that answer at the moment. Please note that you can still expose an Initialize method on your dialog or your dialog's view-model and inject the required dependencies in there instead of relying on a constructor.

Comment: Would I need access to the container instance to do that? I was under the impression (due to lack of experience) that if I needed a reference to the container that I would do so also via dependency injection. If I want to assign references to these services in my modal ViewModal, do I need to do so via the container, and if so, how can I without being supplied the container via DI. I will also continue to research the matter elsewhere but I may not be hitting the right search terms.

Comment: No. You do not need a container at all. A container is nothing but a clever way of accessing dependencies of an object without having to jump through hoops to get them. I believe an IoC container is just another tool that has its advantages and also code smells when used improperly. I use IoC containers for maintaining a dictionary of views so that I can utilize my container for a view object when I need to trigger navigation within my app. I do not use a container for all my dependencies. However, I may inject an IoC container into my viewmodel just like I would inject any other dependency.

Comment: Create the IoC container in your app.cs file and pass it to your main page or your main page's view-model.